# Is there any easier way, than making a driver, for achieving this experiment?

Tags: linux, gpu, driver, linux-device-driver

Am I overcomplicating things, or is this actually the easiest way of doing this?

I need a piece of software, that would allow me to force any given process on a system to use a specific GPU.
The software should be able to force the process to switch GPU mid-execution (yes, I know this will cause a lot of issues, it's part some experiments I'm doing, to hopefully do something smart) (Linux btw)

Would it be correct to make a 'dummy driver' that allowed processes to use it as GPU, and then it could redirect the graphical processing to whatever GPU I wanted, or am I overcomplicating things? Is there an easier way to do this? Cause I kinda don't want to make a driver, but I can't really see any way around it.

Comment: Hey if you ever end up writing that driver i would *love* to see it. sounds cool? in any case, the 1st thing that came to mind is using [virtualization](https://core.vmware.com/blog/virtual-gpus-and-passthrough-gpus-vmware-vsphere-%E2%80%93-can-they-be-used-together) to test this. I'm uncertain whether you can switch while the vm is on. [this](https://mathiashueber.com/windows-virtual-machine-gpu-passthrough-ubuntu/) or [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID3dlVHDl0c) may help, as vmware workstation / virtual box don't support gpu passthrough (or pcie passthroug at all?)

Comment: While i don't have the hardware to support virtual gpus, i could probably create two 'fake' gpus. That would make testing alot easier, as if i f up my driver, it wouldn't damage anything directly.

I thanks for the tip! I don't need to test for performance or anything right now, just how processes would behave. The endgoal would be to do what i call 'execution-hotswap' where you could 'bounce' processes back and forth between gpus.... Though there's a long way to go, and dunno how possible it is... yet

Answer (score 0):

I my view your actually undercomplicating the issue. A GPU is a highly specific device designed to do a gpu`s work like transforming patterns for geometric problems. It is far from a general purpose cpu. Yes, it is a cpu but with alot of specific instruction sets tobe utilized.

So i guess the answer to your question is yes, you can make such a program.
A good hint is to get familiar with specifications like opengl or similar, in order to understand if and how your problem/programm can be made fit for such a engine and give you any advantage. Then you might have a path via Linux kms drivers combined with a wayland based application to interact with your gpu(s).